# draw a circle in ggplot2 that encompases 90% of points

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a very specific problem: basically I have 2000 points on a plot that are stratified in 4 groups of unequal size. I need to illustrate group, BUT I cannot use colour or shape of the points. Instead I want to draw an oval that encompases say 90% of the data. Is there a function for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397097/how-can-a-data-ellipse-be-superimposed-on-a-ggplot2-scatterplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609476/ggplot2-draw-individual-ellipses-but-color-by-group).

Comment: yes this is similar. Unfortunately I need two color schemes: one for the points and one for the elipses. However when I try to make color scheme for the elipse it supresses color scheme for the points. Is it even possible to have 2 color scheme and 2 legends for 2 different geoms?

Comment: Use a a filled marker for the points (e.g., `shape=21` or any value from 21-25) an then use a fill aesthetic for the points and a color aesthetic for the ellipses.

Comment: Yep it works! Thanks