# how to add ellipses in ggplot when using cut in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I'm trying to add ellipses in ggplot (from an ordination in Pkg vegan) based on values that were cut into intervals/groups for coloring purposes using geom_point. I think it is easier if I provide an example using the iris data:

```
data("iris")
T <- metaMDS(iris[1:4]) #perform an ordination with the package vegan
ScIris <- as.data.frame(scores(T)) #extract the values for plotting
RandomNumbers <- runif(150, 1, 100) #generate metaData used for colors
ScIris$test_stat <- RandomNumbers
```

The code below produces the plot with points colored correctly but only adds one ellipse around all the points.

```
ggplot(ScIris, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = cut(test_stat, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 85,95, 99, 100))),
             size = 5) +
   stat_ellipse() +
  scale_color_manual(name = "proportions",
                     values = c("(0,25]" = "black",
                                "(25,50]" = "dark green",
                                  "(50,75]" = "green",
                                  "(75,85]" = "yellow",
                                   "(85,95]" = "orange",
                                    "(95,99]" = "purple",
                                    "(99,100]" = "blue",
                     labels = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "85", "95","<100")))
```

Based on this post [ggplot2 draw individual ellipses but color by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609476/ggplot2-draw-individual-ellipses-but-color-by-group)
I tried modifying the stat_ellipse argument but then nothing will plot correctly.

```
stat_ellipse(aes(x=NMDS1, y=NMDS2, colour = cut(test_stat, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 85,95, 99, 100), group=cut(test_stat, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 85,95, 99, 100)),type = "norm"))
```

How can I add the ellipse for each grouping/cut group? So a black ellipse for points between 0-25, blue ellipse for 99-100, etc. ggplot is great but there is a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the groups on the fly inside `geom_point` (that's what `cut` does) but you need to use the groups again for the ellipses and their colors. So it is better the define the groups first.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("vegan")

data("iris")
T <- metaMDS(iris[1:4]) #perform an ordination with the package vegan

# For reproducibility
set.seed(1234)

ScIris <- as.data.frame(scores(T)) %>%
  mutate(test_stat = runif(150, 1, 100)) %>%
  mutate(group = cut(test_stat, c(0, 25, 50, 75, 85, 95, 99, 100)))

ggplot(ScIris, aes(NMDS1, NMDS2)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group), size = 5) +
  stat_ellipse(aes(color = group, group = group)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "proportions",
                     values = c("(0,25]" = "black",
                                "(25,50]" = "dark green",
                                "(50,75]" = "green",
                                "(75,85]" = "yellow",
                                "(85,95]" = "orange",
                                "(95,99]" = "purple",
                                "(99,100]" = "blue",
                                labels = c("0", "25", "50", "75", "85", "95","<100")))
#> Too few points to calculate an ellipse
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>