# How to make an ellipse as from the car package in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to build a plot showing the difference in variance between the ordinary least squares estimator and the ridge estimator. For this I want to plot contour ellipses for the variance.

The data I'm working with is this:

```
set.seed(10)
sigma = 10
U = rnorm(50,0,sigma) #The errors
X = scale(matrix(rnorm(50*2),ncol=2))
Y = scale(U + X%*%c(5,-2))
```

I then find the ridge(r) and OLS(m) and their covariancematrices:
(**EDIT:** I've realised the covariance matrix for the ridge estimator is wrong, however that doesn't really matter. It will just change the ellipses, not how to plot the.)

```
lbda = 100
r = solve(t(X)%*%X + lbda * diag(2))%*%t(X)%*%Y
m = solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
covmatr = sigma^2 * solve(t(X)%*%X + lbda * diag(2))
covmatm = sigma^2 * solve(t(X)%*%X)
```

I then want to build the plot. In standard R I would do something like this using the function `ellipse` from the `car`-module:

```
library(car)
plot(r[1],r[2],xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5), xlab = TeX("$\\beta_1$"), col="red")
points(m[1],m[2], col="blue")
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)
ellipse(center=c(r),shape=covmatr,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.5,2)), col = "red")
ellipse(center=c(r),shape=covmatr,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.9,2)), col = "red")
ellipse(center=c(m),shape=covmatm,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.5,2)))
ellipse(center=c(m),shape=covmatm,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.9,2)))
```

[image]

*I realize I forgot to rename the y-label*

**My problem is** that I cant figure out how to do the same in `ggplot2`. I have tried:

```
#Building the plot with dots
rd = data.frame(r[1],r[2])
plot1 = ggplot(rd, aes(x=rd$r.1, y = rd$r.2, color = 'r')) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(x=m[1], y=m[2]), colour="blue", size = 3) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    xlim(-5,5) +
    ylim(-5,5) +
    ggtitle(TeX("Varians for ridge"))+
    xlab(TeX("$\\beta_1$")) + ylab("$\\beta_2$")+
    theme_bw()
plot1

#Trying to add ellipses:
ellipse(center=c(r),shape=covmatr,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.5,2)), col = "red")
ellipse(center=c(r),shape=covmatr,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.9,2)), col = "red")
ellipse(center=c(m),shape=covmatm,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.5,2)))
ellipse(center=c(m),shape=covmatm,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.9,2)))
```

However this gives me the following error

```
Fejl i plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I have also tried to simply add the ellipses within the ggplot like this using the ellipse function from the `car` package:

```
plot1 = ... +
    ellipse(center=c(m),shape=covmatm,center.cex=0,radius=sqrt(qchisq(0.9,2)))
```

where "..." depicts that there are lines missing. I know both my attempts are quite naive, however I hoped one would work. I have found the command `stat_ellipse` but this is not useful in my case because as far as I can see it cannot calculate the covariance matrix of the ridge estimator.

Comment: You cannot use base graphics functions (the ones in `car`) with grid graphics functions (the ones in `ggplot`). Look at this[ggplot2 draw individual ellipses but color by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609476/ggplot2-draw-individual-ellipses-but-color-by-group).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I am looking for a `ggplot` version of the `ellipse` function then. I already read the post you link to, but unfortunately it is of no use to me, since they use the `stat_ellipse` function, which is incompatible with my input.
`stat_ellipse` is a `ggplot` version of the `car` function `dataellipse`. I was hoping there also is a `ggplot` version of  `ellipse`.